# How to get a shareable link to a file in iCloud by command line?

Tags: terminal, icloud, command-line, file-sharing

[There is a way to share files on my iCloud, one by one, with a shareable link](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl91854a7a/mac). It's badly named "Add People".

I use it often to send files to my friends or family. When it's more files, I just zip them. But obtaining the link is tedious, clicking on many things. Perhaps this can be done by command line or it can be scripted?

The only option I'm interested in is "Share > Add People > Anyone with the link, View only > Copy Link" I'd like to do this programmatically, either using shell or Python.